# Which word(s) can be used to express causal relation in modern English?

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions, formality, colloquialisms

> I will skip it over, because nobody will have doubt on this.
>
> Since nobody will have doubt on this, I will skip it over.
>
> I will skip it over, for nobody will have doubt on this.

An American friend told me that we should avoid using “for” or “since” when describing a causal relation.

Is this true? I feel that these three sentence have no differences at all.

Comment: I would suggest - I will skip over this. Unless someone has a question?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I agree. *skip over* is not a separable prefix verb even though its a phrasal verb.

Comment: You "skip over" something; "I'll skip over it" is preferable to "I will skip over it". The full verb form " I will" sounds a bit odd next to a colloquial expression.

Comment: I donot know why "skip over" cannot be separated in sentences. Can somebody explain it for me?

Comment: Because you skip _over_ something, not skip something _over_. The same would be true for similar verbs like _hop_ and _jump_; it's: _The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog_, not, _The quick brown fox jumps the lazy dog over_.

Comment: Nobody says “will have doubt”. Nobody.

Comment: This question appears to be more closely suited for the English Language Learners StackExchange site.

Answer (score 4):

*because*, *since*, *after*, *for*, *as* and *of* can all express causation, with *because* being the strongest, most explicit *single word* doing so. All can be used correctly; you were probably told to use *because* based on the explicit causation of the word.

He died **because** he had cancer.
**Since** his cancer had left him immunocompromised, he died.
He died **after** his cancer metastasized to his brain.
He died, **for** his cancer had metastasized to his brain. (formal and out of general use)
**As** he had no immunity following chemotherapy, he died.
He died **of** an overwhelming infection.

As the word becomes weaker, sentence structure must become stronger to show causation, so, if not paying attention, it is probably a good thing to remember that **because** will not fail you. Having said that, all of your sentences show causation, for you have constructed them well.

Comment: A comprehensive and well reasoned answer. As an aside, I'm also in favour of dropping the capital (eg 'because' here) where it seems counter-productive, pattern-destroying. Have you a reference one can fend off traditionalists with?

Answer (score 2):

Your examples (with corrections irrelevant to your point):

> I will skip over it, because nobody will have any doubts about this.
>
> Since nobody will have any doubts about this, I will skip over it.
>
> I will skip over it, for nobody will have any doubts about this.

are all grammatical. The first two are perfectly idiomatic; the third one, with *for* is a little bit literary or old-fashioned.

[Another point unrelated to your question: in the first and third, it would probably be best to swap *it* and *this*, so that *it* refers back, as it does in the middle one].

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps causality is at least present in a weakly sense in the combination of "and" and "then":

He took a sip from the chalice *and then* passed away.

Comment: Post-hoc-ergo-propter-hockery?